# R-text connection

Tags: r, text

I need to create a table with the following data (I don't want to use a csv to import it).

```
toread<-"DomicLabProv   cluster
BUENOS AIRES    1
CHUBUT  1
FORMOSA 1
LA PAMPA    1
SAN JUAN    1
CAPITAL FEDERAL 1
MISIONES    1
SAN LUIS    1
SANTA FE    1
ENTRE RIOS  2
JUJUY   2
LA RIOJA    2
SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO 2
CHACO   2
CORDOBA 2
CORRIENTES  2
SALTA   2
TIERRA DEL FUEGO    2
TUCUMAN 2
CATAMARCA   3
MENDOZA 3
NEUQUEN 3
RIO NEGRO   3
SANTA CRUZ  3
"
```

As you can see first and second fields are separated by tabs.
When I try:

```
read.table(textConnection(toread), header = TRUE)
```

I get the following error mesage:

> Error in scan. Line 2 hasn't got 2 elements.

I think this is related with the fact that names in DomicLabProv have spaces, for example "Buenos Aires". Is there a way to overcome this issue? I mean those are spaces done by space bar and the ones that are between fields are done by the tab key.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace your delimiting spaces by a `,` and add `sep=','` in your read.table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a `textConnection`; pass the string to the function `read.table` via the `text` option instead:

```
read.delim(text = toread)
```

(`read.delim` is the same as `read.table` but uses tabs as delimiters, and defaults to having a header.)

This works if your text is indeed delimited by the tab character `'\t'`. If that isn’t the case, a bit more work is required, as you need to manually split the columns, while taking care not to split fields like “LA PAMPA”, which also contains a space. This is finicky and best avoided by having the data in the right format to start with. In your particular case, we can use the information that the second column is numeric (but we first need to remove the header, since that doesn’t conform):

```
header = strsplit(sub('\n.*', '', toread), ' +')[[1]]
no_header = sub('^.*?\n', '', toread)
no_header = gsub(' +(?=\\d)', '\t', no_header, perl = TRUE)
data = read.delim(text = no_header, header = FALSE)
colnames(data) = header
```

Comment: Thanks but the result doens't split columns. I get:    DomicLabProvcluster
1         BUENOS AIRES1
2               CHUBUT1

Comment: @GabyLP Then your data isn’t actually tab-separated as claimed. However, my answer does address this. Copying and pasting your data into R and then running the second piece of code definitely works.

Comment: You are right. I copied the data from an Excel spreadsheet, and  I supposed it was copied separated by tabs. I checked that, erasing each space and pressing tab key, and still got the wrong result. I just copied from here and worked. Can't explain why. Maybe someone edited the text.

Answer (score -1):

With a little regex, we can convert it to CSV format:

```
read.csv(text = sub('\\s+(\\S+$)', ',\\1', readLines(textConnection(toread))))
#           DomicLabProv cluster
# 1         BUENOS AIRES       1
# 2               CHUBUT       1
# 3              FORMOSA       1
# 4             LA PAMPA       1
# 5             SAN JUAN       1
# 6      CAPITAL FEDERAL       1
# 7             MISIONES       1
# 8             SAN LUIS       1
# 9             SANTA FE       1
# 10          ENTRE RIOS       2
# 11               JUJUY       2
# 12            LA RIOJA       2
# 13 SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO       2
# 14               CHACO       2
# 15             CORDOBA       2
# 16          CORRIENTES       2
# 17               SALTA       2
# 18    TIERRA DEL FUEGO       2
# 19             TUCUMAN       2
# 20           CATAMARCA       3
# 21             MENDOZA       3
# 22             NEUQUEN       3
# 23           RIO NEGRO       3
# 24          SANTA CRUZ       3
```

`sub` looks for whitespace characters `\\s+` followed by a group that it captures `(...)`, which consists of anything but whitespace characters `\\S+` followed by the end of the line `$`. It replaces them with a comma `,` followed by the captured group `\\1`.